How do I use crewAI's PDFSearchTool with a custom endpoint?
I tried to initialize the tool with
pdf_tool = PDFSearchTool(
    config=dict(
        llm=dict(
            provider="azure_openai",
                config=dict(
                    model=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME"),
                    api_key=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"),
                    azure_endpoint=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"),
                    temperature=0.0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    pdf=document
)

But that raises a schema.SchemaError: Key 'llm' error:
Key 'config' error:
Wrong key 'azure_endpoint' `

The correct key for the PDFSearchTool config dictionary is: base_url=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT")

Sorry, that was not the final answer. While the key base_url prevents a schema error, the tool still tries to connect to the original OpenAI endpoint and not the one given in base_url.
